# CSS match previous sibling element's width (extend background color to overflow content)

Tags: html, css, width

I have two elements within a div and they both have different background colors. The first div may sometime overflow (due to dynamic content) and because of that the background-color does not extend to cover the overflowed content.

**Example code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .header {
      text-size-adjust: 100%;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      line-height: 1.4rem;
      z-index: 10;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0px 3.2rem;
      gap: 1.6rem;
      height: 5.5rem;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgb(177, 187, 205);
      box-sizing: unset;
    }

    .app {
      max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .sub-header {
      display: flex;
      gap: 24px;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 32px 64px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 112px;
      background-color: rgb(42, 49, 65);
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .content {
      padding: 2.4rem 6.4rem;
      background-color: rgb(229, 232, 238);
    }
    .content p {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="header">
      <div>Header 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="sub-header">
        <button>Button #1</button>
        <button>Button #2</button>
        <button>Button #3</button>
        <button>Button #4</button>
        <button>Button #5</button>
        <button>Button #6</button>
        <button>Button #7</button>
        <button>Button #8</button>
        <button>Button #9</button>
        <button>Button #10</button>
        <button>Button #11</button>
        <button>Button #12</button>
        <button>Button #13</button>
        <button>Button #14</button>
        <button>Button #15</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis est condimentum, consequat nisi nec,
          consequat metus. Maecenas feugiat ligula sit amet odio suscipit sodales ac vel mauris. Maecenas tempus, dui
          sed pulvinar mattis, massa justo tempor justo, ac condimentum odio diam ut lacus. Praesent in odio a lacus
          viverra ultricies non a est.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Ltwav18c/

What can I do to make sure that the background colors for both the divs (`sub-header` and `content`) extend to its overflowed content.

[image: Background color doesn't extend to overflowed content]

The `content` div doesn't overflow, only the `sub-header` div does.

I tried setting sub-header div's `width: fit-content` and `min-width: 100%` and that extends the `background-color` to cover all its content and if it doesn't overflow, then it extends to the viewport size.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Ltwav18c/1/

**But the issue** with this is that the second div's width doesn't extend and so it remains at `100%`. I want the second div to match the first div's width always.

[image: Background color for second div doesn't extend to match first div]

FYI, I cannot modify the CSS for the parent divs (`app` and `header`) as they're controlled by a different app and my app is being embedded.

Comment: Hello, subheader could take a `min-width:max-content;` to fully extends its content when the viewport's width is not enough. **If** your HTML is embedded within the HTML of that app and CSS linked (or inline) to the parents app itself, why cannot you add extra CSS rules for `.app` ?  `.app{display:grid;}` would be enough to have all its children fully covering the app's width. https://jsfiddle.net/6w93yf0g/ If the source code reflects your snippet, you should be able to add css rules to any tagsof the page. Else, which is the method embedding your .sub-header/.content ? iframe, object ?

Comment: in short, can you clarify how ... *-and my app is being embedded.* .. and/or which source code it gives for HTML rendered?

Comment: It's embedded through Module Federation. But I do see that `display: grid` works and I can wrap the `sub-header` and `content` divs into another div and have it be a `display:grid`.

Comment: One question, is it not possible with display: flex? Is display: grid necessary?

Comment: Nop, grid is the one to pickup. Flex has another purpose :) That is for an extra parent you use yourself or for the display layout to set to .app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider wrapping `.sub-header` and `.content` in a grid layout. The `width: fit-content` of `.sub-header` causes the grid column track to be as wide as `.sub-header`. This then gives `.content` more room to fill, thus matching `.sub-header`'s width:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 3.2rem;
  gap: 1.6rem;
  height: 5.5rem;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgb(177, 187, 205);
  box-sizing: unset;
}

.app {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.sub-header {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 32px 64px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 112px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 49, 65);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  padding: 2.4rem 6.4rem;
  background-color: rgb(229, 232, 238);
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div>Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="app">
    <div style="display: grid">
      <div class="sub-header">
        <button>Button #1</button>
        <button>Button #2</button>
        <button>Button #3</button>
        <button>Button #4</button>
        <button>Button #5</button>
        <button>Button #6</button>
        <button>Button #7</button>
        <button>Button #8</button>
        <button>Button #9</button>
        <button>Button #10</button>
        <button>Button #11</button>
        <button>Button #12</button>
        <button>Button #13</button>
        <button>Button #14</button>
        <button>Button #15</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis est condimentum, consequat nisi nec, consequat metus. Maecenas feugiat ligula sit amet odio suscipit sodales ac vel mauris. Maecenas tempus, dui sed pulvinar mattis, massa justo tempor
          justo, ac condimentum odio diam ut lacus. Praesent in odio a lacus viverra ultricies non a est.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternative solution using flex:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px 3.2rem;
  gap: 1.6rem;
  height: 5.5rem;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid rgb(177, 187, 205);
  box-sizing: unset;
}

.app {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.sub-header {
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 32px 64px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 112px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 49, 65);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  padding: 2.4rem 6.4rem;
  background-color: rgb(229, 232, 238);
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">
    <div>Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="app">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: fit-content;">
      <div class="sub-header">
        <button>Button #1</button>
        <button>Button #2</button>
        <button>Button #3</button>
        <button>Button #4</button>
        <button>Button #5</button>
        <button>Button #6</button>
        <button>Button #7</button>
        <button>Button #8</button>
        <button>Button #9</button>
        <button>Button #10</button>
        <button>Button #11</button>
        <button>Button #12</button>
        <button>Button #13</button>
        <button>Button #14</button>
        <button>Button #15</button>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis est condimentum, consequat nisi nec, consequat metus. Maecenas feugiat ligula sit amet odio suscipit sodales ac vel mauris. Maecenas tempus, dui sed pulvinar mattis, massa justo tempor
          justo, ac condimentum odio diam ut lacus. Praesent in odio a lacus viverra ultricies non a est.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This should fix the issue.

Question, is it possible to fix this with a flexbox layout somehow (i.e. `display: flex`)? Or is `display: grid` the only possible solution?

Comment: I believe it could be possible to fix this with a flexbox layout somehow. I don't think `display: grid` is the only solution.

Comment: If possible do you mind sharing/explaining on how it can be fixed with a flex layout? I have accepted the current answer anyways as it fixes my problem and I'll probably go with that. Was just curious of how it can be fixed with flex layout.

Much thanks!

Comment: Added a flex layout solution.